# Bokeh generates PropertyValueList error when trying to update MultiSelect widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm playing with `MultiSelect` widget and I got it to a point where it generates an error that I cannot explain it.

Here is the working code *without* errors:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Slider, Select, TextInput, MultiSelect

df = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes"]

def callback(attr, old, new):
    print(df)
    print("{} changed: Old [ {} ] -> New [ {} ]".format(attr, old, new))
#    multiselect1.update(options = [x for x in df if new in x])


multiselect1 = MultiSelect(title = "multiselect1",
                           name = "multiselect1",
                           value = [],
                           options = df)
multiselect1.on_change('value', callback)

curdoc().add_root(widgetbox(multiselect1))
```

The printed out is what was expected:

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']
value changed: Old [ [] ] -> New [ ['oranges'] ]
```

That much about working part...
For the *not working part*...as soon as `multiselect1.update(options = [x for x in df if new in x])` is commented in and the new `callback` function is :

```
def callback(attr, old, new):
    print(df)
    print("{} changed: Old [ {} ] -> New [ {} ]".format(attr, old, new))
    multiselect1.update(options = [x for x in df if new in x])
```

...it generates the *error*:

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']
value changed: Old [ [] ] -> New [ ['oranges'] ]
2018-05-17 13:34:48,755 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): TypeError("'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not PropertyValueList",)
```

Any idea why this error is generated and how it can be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the variable `new` is a list, whereas the list comprehension below needs `new` to be a string:

```
[x for x in df if new in x]
```

You could try indexing the `new` list to get the string value like so:

```
[x for x in df if new[0] in x]
```